# How to automate Microsoft Edge using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, selenium, automation, webdriver, microsoft-edge

Since IE11 is retiring soon, I was attempting to re-write my PS Scripts to automate MS Edge. I have searched online and apparently I need [edgedriver_win64](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) and a WebDriver testing framework like [Selenium 4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver). I have either got the links wrong or the logic wrong. But when I tried to install the driver, it just opened a command prompt saying "MSEdgeDriver was started successfully". Nothing was installed. And I have absolutely no idea of how to install Selenium 4. If someone could help me prep my PC so I can automate using MS Edge via PowerShell, I will be really grateful. Additionally some pointers on how to use these for automation via PowerShell will be big help.

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to use PowerShell? Why not a proper programming language like C#/Java? There are millions of tutorials and guides on how to automate using the Selenium+Edge combination. But i think you will find very minimum amount of help online fpr powershell.

Comment: check the background process for edge, it should have started headless. I m not sure of getting it done by powershell.

Comment: How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462782/powershell-ms-edge-automation/71478011#71478011) helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Think "Driver" more along the lines of golf-cart vs Daemon... the executable launches a http server on the localhost which is used to create and steer browser sessions via http requests on the given port number. The framework, in your case Selenium, then connects to this server and provides an object based API for the programming language to interact with.

Answer (score 3):

The regular way to automate Edge with WebDriver is using C#, Python, Java like [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp), not PowerShell. If you really need to use PowerShell, you can use [Selenium PowerShell Module](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell). You can refer to the steps below:

1. Run `Install-Module Selenium` in Windows PowerShell.
2. Download corresponding version of Edge WebDriver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) (same version as your Edge browser).
3. Put the Edge WebDriver *msedgedriver.exe* into folder *C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Selenium\3.0.1\assemblies* (the path is where you install Selenium PowerShell Module, you can change it according to your real situation).
4. Rename *msedgedriver.exe* to *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe*.
5. Sample PowerShell code:

   ```
   $Driver = Start-SeEdge
   Enter-SeUrl https://www.google.com -Driver $Driver
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I use VBA in MSACCESS to open the browser with PowerShell.
In the reference library in the database, Selenium type library is selected.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function EDGE_OPEN()

Set obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
obj.ShellExecute "microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com/"

End Function
```

Comment: Although this launches MS edge, it does not allow automation of Edge (other than launching the initial page) and means that you are unable to interact with the webpages. The OP was asking for guidance on setting up Selenium and Edge driver.

Answer (score -2):

powershell example of above:

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/"
$obj = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$obj.ShellExecute("microsoft-edge:$url")
```

Comment: Although this launches MS edge, it does not allow automation of Edge (other than launching the initial page) and means that you are unable to interact with the webpages. The OP was asking for guidance on setting up Selenium and Edge driver.